Nuda per lusus pectora nostra patent
I thought it would be a simple thing to translate this phrase from Ovid, even though I know no latin myself at all. But it turns out that there are various translations floating around and I have no means of understanding where the ambiguities come from. I would appreciate your help.
So from Ovid

Nuda per lusus pectora nostra patent.

seems to mean something like games being a good way to truly get to know a person. Fine. But depending on the translation, I find some variations, and not knowing latin myself I'm completely lost:

some talk about games, some about fights. Perhaps as in a gladiator's figh game? Would the modern translation be in line with "games", as in e.g. board games?

some talk about breasts, heart, or soul. Are these words really ambiguous in latin? Or which one would it be?

Finally, I read of naked breasts and open hearts and accessible souls... is either possible? Could one interpret any erotic connotation into this phrase?


Thank you very much for your help!

The line is Ars amatoria 3, 372. A very literal translation would be:

Our bare breasts lay open through games.

Obviously Ovid was not talking about not wearing clothing on the upper body. The breast was (and is) considered – to quote Lewis & Short, a reputable Latin dictionary – “the seat of affection,” and thus, pectus could refer to the feelings, disposition, mind of a person.
Thus, it might be more clear in English to write: “Through games, our true disposition becomes apparent.” That is not very poetic, though. J. H. Mozley, in the Loeb Classical Library, translates the line as: “in our games, our hearts show clear to see.”
Ludus can also refer to circus games, which in Rome were often bloody and included gladiatorial fights (often to the death). But that is not the case here. Ovid recommends (to womankind) to play games with men to win them over, but warns that one must not become too engrossed in the zeal for victory, or the disappointment of defeat, if one wishes to please any man. He is referring quite literally to simple, recreational games that are appropriate for women to play: throwing dice, games of skill, board games (he gives a few examples, one sounding slightly like chess).
Thus, talking about “fights” is inappropriate. Talking about “naked breasts,” while that is literally what it says, should not be construed to have any erotic connotation: The danger here is turning off a man one might actually want to please; baring too much of one's actual breast, whatever else might be said about it, does not usually entail that danger.

Wow, thank you!
